# How to rename Model without altering Table in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, orm

We simply want to rename a Django model while preserving the existing DB table name.

It would seem that the Meta field [db_table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#db-table) would do this, except apparently this acts as an instruction to migrate, which then generates a migration `AlterModelTable` to change the actual table.

Additionally, the ideal solution would be understood by `makemigrations` so that it does not repeatedly try to generate some `ALTER` statement.

I am shocked, because this suggests to me that the database table name is not configurable. This seems so basic. Surely there is a way?

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555911/django-renaming-model-field-without-alter-table-on-the-database), but that one is about renaming a field: [Django renaming model field without ALTER TABLE on the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62555911/django-renaming-model-field-without-alter-table-on-the-database).

Comment: There are several migrations that turn out to have no effect on the database. Anothe one is `choices`. Some backands *could* indeed enforce this, but afaik, none do.